# Pause mediaelement.js using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, mediaelement.js

I have initialised the element using:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer();
```

Now I would like to target that video and pause it when a link is pressed:

```
$('.page_button').live('click', function() {
    $('video').pause();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each element with a media player element has a player property defined.  This is where all the  methods reside.  You can access it with either of the following methods:

```
$('video')[0].player.pause(); // Be sure the video element exists.

$('video').each(function(){this.player.pause()}) // Safe.
```

Comment: Important note: this only works if you explicitly create the `player` object using the `var player = new MediaElementPlayer(...` method.

Comment: One important detail: for the `play()` and `pause()` methods to work, you need to create the player object explicitly by using the `var player = new MediaElementPlayer()` method, as described at http://mediaelementjs.com. If you do that, even a simple `player.pause()` will do the trick.