# How to control mediaelement.js player from external links?

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I want to play and pause mediaelement.js player using external links not the player controls itself.

How to do that?

EDIT: just to make the question more clear.

I initialized mediaelements.js player using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#wp_mep_1').mediaelementplayer({
        m:1
        ,features: ['playpause','tracks','fullscreen']
        ,audioWidth:26,audioHeight:26
    });
});
```

Now I have a link for the song file just next to the player. I play or pause the player next to the link when the link is clicked.

I tried this code and it works but it creates a new player independent of the one already initialized:

```
$(".songlink").click(function() {
    player = MediaElementPlayer($(this).siblings(".mejs-container").find("audio"));
    if (player.playing) {
        player.pause();
    } else {
        player.play();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Is it possible to control the player like this:

```
$('#wp_mep_1').mediaelementplayer(play);
```

Comment: How to open this question again?

Comment: The question is how to use mediaelements.js events on a player that is already there without creating a new object.

Comment: Access of the player is different: Try this:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729305/pause-mediaelement-js-using-jquery

Comment: the code from that question is not working. it says "player is not a function"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, after I lost too much hair I decided to do that by triggering a click on the mediaelment player controls when the link is clicked.

I cant believe such good script does not have flexible api and good documentation.

Here is the code that work for me:

```
$(".songlink").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".mejs-container").find(".mejs-button")[0].click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can only agree on the missing documented API. I also used your solution before. Unfortunately, now I need to manipulate the volume, creating a fade out on it before pausing the audio.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find everything you need on this page:   https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/wiki/Events-and-Methods
(Or on the other pages in the wiki.)

**EDIT:**
For calling events on a player that already exists simply get it out of the dom:
eg: `$('#wp_mep_1').play()`

Comment: The question is how to use these events on a player that is already there without creating a new object.

Comment: Yes of course. You can just trigger the events of the player. Imagine a button you create yourself(or anything else you can imagine...) and once you click on it whatever event you want(for example play the mediaplayer) gets triggered.

Comment: The problem is that Media Methods like `play()` or `pause()` need a certain context to work, they arent globally defined. Just doing `$('#wp_mep_1').play()` in your script gives an "undefined is not a function" Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: **Update:** In order for this to work, it's mandatory to create the mediaplayer object using the `var player = new MediaElementPlayer(...` method, as described at http://mediaelementjs.com/.

Comment: More detail please, this plugin is woefully documented